# Background-image não aparece

Tags: html, css

Hospedei três imagens para colocar na minha pagina como background-image do header, footer e em uma tag img, mas elas não aparecem. Coloquei da seguinte forma:

```css
.rodape{
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(https://ibb.co/TwVWfw5);
  background-size: 30%;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
}

.cabecalho{
  background-image: url('https://ibb.co/n3y80Vq');
  padding: 0;
}

.logo{
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<section class="centro">
<header class="cabecalho">
  <div class="cabecalho-container">
    <div class="cabecalho-top">
      <div>
        <img src="https://ibb.co/qnRQqss" alt="logo da pagina" class="logo">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <!--conteudo da pagina-->
  
  <footer class="rodape">
<p> rodape </p>
</footer>

</section>
```

Comment: Você adicionou imagens aos elementos `.cabecalho` e `.rodape`, mas no seu código já apenas o `.logo`.

Comment: foi apenas para mostrar como coloquei os links das imagens, mas colocarei o restante

Comment: Esse é o link da imagem https://i.ibb.co/X4zR0ss/game-console.png, e não esse que vc usou https://ibb.co/TwVWfw5 o codigo está certo, vc que não pegou o link correto da imagem

Comment: tudo tranquilo? Acredito que seja a falta de aspas no background-image, dar uma olhada aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/background-image Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o link do Fiddle JS abaixo com as imagens funcionando. Basicamente precisava abrir a imagem em uma nova guia e pegar o link especifico da imagem.

**Funcionando:
https://jsfiddle.net/a03m4jxf/3/**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]